# window opener manipulation; Add a text to a element in parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pop up window which user can select files and then it will alert the selected image's URL.  But I need to do more than that.

I am looking for a way to insert the URL to the parent window's input element.

```
window.opener.document.write(url);
```

This will overwrite the parent window's content. But I need to add the URL to special input element in parent window.

I was just thinking what if this literally works !

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("image").write(url);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("image").value = url;
```